# I need to order a list that is dependant on another list. how to change both lists?

Tags: matlab, list

I have a Matlab program that generates a list x =  6.1692    8.1863    5.8092    8.2754    6.0891    the program also outputs another list aspl =  680   637   669   599   693.

The two lists are on equal length and the first element in list x is related to the first element in list aspl. I need to graph the two lists but want list aspl to be in order from smallest to largest. How would I go about doing this? If I need to move the first element in aspl to position 4 in the list, then the first element of list x also needs to be moved to position 4 in list x. The numbers above are not important they are just examples, the actual program generates hundereds of numbers.

for example x =  6.1692    8.1863    5.8092    8.2754 initially

```
     aspl =  680   637   669   599   693
```

after changing aspl to ascending order this is how x should look.

x =   5.8092  8.1863  5.8092  6.1692  8.2754

aspl =  599  637   669  680   693

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the second output of sort:

```
%# sort aspl, get new order of aspl
[sortedAspl, sortOrder] = sort(aspl);
%# reorder x the same way as aspl
sortedX = x(sortOrder);
```