# MATLAB help for having the vertices corresponding to area

Tags: matlab

I have a program in matlab which draws a bounding box. It displays the area of every blob.I have arranged the areas in descending order.
 Now i want to have the verticesX and vertixesY corresponding to the area which i have arranged in descending order to use it further. Can u please tell how to have it?

```
clear all;

close all;

clc

I=imread('image.jpg');
......
bw2=im2bw(J(:,:,2),L);

subplot(2,3,4);
imshow(bw2);

% Label each blob so we can make measurements of it

[labeledImage numberOfBlobs] = bwlabel(bw2, 8);

% Get all the blob properties.

blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'BoundingBox','Area');

allBlobAreas = [blobMeasurements.Area];

% Loop through all blobs, putting up Bounding Box.
hold on; 

for k = 1 : numberOfBlobs

boundingBox = blobMeasurements(k).BoundingBox;   % Get box.

x1 = boundingBox(1);

y1 = boundingBox(2);

x2 = x1 + boundingBox(3) - 1;

y2 = y1 + boundingBox(4) - 1;

verticesX = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];

verticesY = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];

% Calculate width/height ratio.

aspectRatio(k) = boundingBox(3) / boundingBox(4);

fprintf('\n For blob #%d, area = %d, aspect ratio = %.2f\n' ,k, allBlobAreas(k), aspectRatio(k));

fprintf('\n VerticesofX=[%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f],VerticesofY=[%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f]\n',verticesX,verticesY);

%% Loop for having area in descending order
x(k)=allBlobAreas(k);

for i=1:length(x)-1

for j=i+1:length(x)

if x(i)<x(j)

c=x(i);

x(i)=x(j);

x(j)=c;

end
end
end
end
%% Displays area in descending order
disp(x)
```

Comment: That's not a program, it's a few lines of text.  Help us to help you, format code blocks as code blocks.  Look at the little icons above the text area when you are writing questions (and answers).  For code you ought, generally, to use the icon bearing the {} characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to order a list that is dependant on another list. how to change both lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512864/i-need-to-order-a-list-that-is-dependant-on-another-list-how-to-change-both-lis)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the `sort` function built-in to MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html)

`[B,IX]=sort(A)` will sort a vector and return the indices that convert A into sorted-A.

```
[B,IX]=sort(allBlobAreas,'descend');
sortedAreas=B; % equivalent to sortedAreas=allBlobAreas(IX);
sortedVerticesX=verticesX(IX);
sortedVerticesY=verticesY(IX);
```

This will also let you replace your sorting algorithm with something much simpler.