# How to sort centroids kmeans

Tags: matlab, colormap, centroid

I must use the unmonitored algorithm kmeans like this:

```
[idx,C]=kmeans(kindex,k,'emptyaction', 'singleton');
```

I will have two idx and C vectors.
For example,in my code for k=4 (clusters):

`idx1----> C=-2
idx2----> C=0,23
idx3----> C=0,8
idx4----> C=0,53`

I want to sort C vector respect idx like this:

`idx1----> C=-2
idx2----> C=0,23
idx3----> C=0,53
idx4----> C=0,8`

I want that min(C) has blu color and max(C) has red color with colormap, but if idx1 is not min(C) (because C isn't sort) I can't do this.

How can I order C? I used sortrows but this function sort C but not respect idx.

thank you for answer.

**EDIT:**

This is an example pick with my current values of C:

[image: image1]

You can see idx3 (color like yellow) and idx4 (color red) but, idx4 is not max(C)-->0,8 .. max(C) is idx3--> 0,53

I really have to reorder the centroid.

Comment: Something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512864/i-need-to-order-a-list-that-is-dependant-on-another-list-how-to-change-both-lis)?

Comment: Then, for my program I need to do something like this: `[C_sort, idx_sort]=sort(C);
ordidx=idx(idx_sort);`  ? Don't work.

Comment: Then you'll need to explain more fully what result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: See my Edit, I added an example

Comment: Upp.. How Can I do?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may do the trick is to feed the sorted centroids of the first call to **kmeans** back into kmeans as **centroid** seeds, using the 'start' option. The new "C" will be sorted and the new "idx" will correspond to this sorted "C".

```
[idx,C]=kmeans(kindex,k);

[idx,C]=kmeans(kindex,k,'start',sort(C))
```